# How to set random wallpaper image on light-locker?

Tags: lightdm, light-locker

I'm using light-locker as my lockscreen for my Arch Linux pc. Every time the lockscreen comes up there is this black white background image of a shoe store (seems to be the default). I really dislike it. Is there a possibility to set it to a random background image, preferably from some folder on my pc?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#Changing_background_images.2Fcolors

Comment: webkit2 greeter it is then @jasonwryan

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your preferences for wallpapers but if you want I suggest you to try [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1262/bing-wallpaper-changer/) GNOME extension. However, it goes without saying you must have GNOME shell on your Arch Linux.

Comment: Looks great, just not so interested to download the GNOME shell